# Setting dynamic password from Maven

Tags: maven, access-token, system-properties

We've started using an AWS CodeArtifact Maven repository.  Before connecting, developers must run a command ("aws") to acquire a temporary access token.  How can I configure Maven to acquire and use this token automatically, without requiring running a script, configuring an IDE or changing the simple command line "mvn install"?

Maybe there's a trick I'm overlooking.

The token must be "interpolated" in the element <server>/<password> in settings.xml.  This file will pre-process either an environment variable ({$env.token}) or a Java system property ({$token}).  It will not process a project property.

- The repository password cannot be specified within the POM file.

  The settings.xml file cannot use project properties.

  The exec-maven-plugin cannot set an environment variable in the parent process (Windows).  It can write to a file.

  The properties-maven-plugin cannot set a dynamic system property (e.g., from a file or script output).

  The surefire plugin binds to the test phase and forks a JVM.

  The Windows setx command does not affect the running process.

UPDATE:  Maven downloads repository metadata before the first phase, so no plugin will solve the problem.

Comment: Have you already taken a look at [AWS CodeArtifact Maven Proxy](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/aws-codeartifact-maven-proxy)?

Comment: I'm fascinated that somebody else has thought about the problem and created a solution.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it.  Though, a more convenient solution would be a wagon that sets certain system properties, including a TTL, from a shell script.  That would work with AWS SSO as well.

Comment: well, there is wagon extension on GH: https://github.com/OneGeek/codeartifact-maven-wagon

Comment: That's better.  No configuration is needed in settings.xml and the token is not written to a file.  However, it connects to AWS twice for every repository access.  It's open source and simple code, so caching could be added. Thanks!